# Extracting enum values from ctags file

Tags: c, vim, ctags

Is it possible, using ctags with Vim, to extract all the enum values for a given enum?

For example, if I have the following enum type:

```
typedef enum fruit {
    APPLE,
    ORANGE,
    PEAR,
} fruit_t;
```

which generates the following lines in my tags file (using default `--c-kinds`):

```
APPLE   minex.c /^    APPLE,$/;"    e   enum:fruit  file:
ORANGE  minex.c /^    ORANGE,$/;"   e   enum:fruit  file:
PEAR    minex.c /^    PEAR,$/;" e   enum:fruit  file:
fruit   minex.c /^typedef enum fruit$/;"    g   file:
fruit_t minex.c /^    } fruit_t;$/;"    t   typeref:enum:fruit  file:
```

is there any way of specifying `fruit` or `fruit_t` and obtaining the values `[ 'APPLE', 'ORANGE', 'PEAR' ]`?

In Vim I had hoped that `:tselect fruit` would do the trick, but it doesn't.

Of course I could grep the tags file and process the results myself, but for a very large file this would be expensive, and I am hoping there is a built-in way of getting such basic information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, by filtering the results of the `taglist()` function, which give you a convenient programmatic access to the tags database.

```
:echo map(filter(taglist('.*'), 'has_key(v:val, "enum") && v:val.enum ==# "fruit"'), 'v:val.name')
['APPLE', 'ORANGE', 'PEAR']
```

What this does is:

1. Get *all* tags (`.*` regular expression)
2. Keep (`filter()`) all tags that have (`has_key()`) an `enum` attribute, and whose name is exactly (`==#`) `fruit`.
3. From the resulting objects, select (`map()`) only the `name` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.